# Page renders faster than my data can be fetched

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to display some long and latitude data on a map when the page is loaded but it seems my page is rendered faster than the data can be fetched.

The data is retrieved properly I have tested the api call.

Can anyone see what I am missing

I tried using useEffect hook but that still does not seem to work:

here is my component:

```
import react from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Popup, Polyline } from "react-leaflet";
import axios from "axios";
import polyline from "@mapbox/polyline";

function Map() {
  const [activites, setActivities] = useState([]);
  const [polylines, setPolylines] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setActivitieData();
    setPolylineArray();
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  const getActivityData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/data");

    return response.data;
  };

  const setActivitieData = async () => {
    const activityData = await getActivityData();
    setActivities(activityData);
  };

  const setPolylineArray = () => {
    const polylineArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < activites.length; i++) {
      const polylineData = activites[i].map.summary_polyline;
      const activityName = activites[i].name;
      polylineArray.push({ positions: polyline.decode(polylineData), name: activityName });
    }
    setPolylines(polylineArray);
    console.log("Polyline array = ", polylineArray);
  };

  return !isLoading ? (
    <MapContainer center={[37.229564, -120.047533]} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ width: "100%", height: "calc(100vh - 4rem)" }}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {polylines.map((activity, idx) => (
        <Polyline key={idx} positions={activity.positions}>
          <Popup>
            <div>
              <h2>{"Name: " + activity.name}</h2>
            </div>
          </Popup>
        </Polyline>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <p>Loading</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have a better time with

- a data loading library such as [`swr`](https://swr.vercel.app/) to deal with the state related to getting data from your API (beyond just `data`, you might be interested in e.g. `isError` and `isValidating`; please refer to the docs),
- and [`useMemo` for the derived polyline state](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo) (because it is always purely derivable from the `activities` you've fetched, and doesn't need to be separately updated state).

Something like this (I'm understandably unable to test this without your API and all, but it should work).

```
import { MapContainer, Polyline, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import axios from "axios";
import polyline from "@mapbox/polyline";
import React from "react";
import useSWR from "swr";

function getJSON(url) {
  return axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
}

function Map() {
  const activitySWR = useSWR("http://localhost:8080/api/data", getJSON);
  const activities = activitySWR.data ?? null;
  const polylines = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!activities) return null; // no data yet
    const polylineArray = [];
    for (const item of activities) {
      const polylineData = item.map.summary_polyline;
      polylineArray.push({ positions: polyline.decode(polylineData), name: item.name });
    }
    return polylineArray;
  }, [activities]);
  if (!activities) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[37.229564, -120.047533]}
      zoom={15}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "calc(100vh - 4rem)" }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      {polylines.map((activity, idx) => (
        <Polyline key={idx} positions={activity.positions}>
          <Popup>
            <div>
              <h2>{`Name: ${activity.name}`}</h2>
            </div>
          </Popup>
        </Polyline>
      ))}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: I was thinking that reaching for SWR is likely a good answer as well given it's ease of use for a complicated topic. Also nice job on handing a load state. I think the only other scenario that should be taken into consideration as well would be an error state to fully complete this 

Comment: @CTS_AE Thanks. The original implementation didn't care about error handling either, but I did edit in a mention to the other props available on the SWR object :)

Comment: @AKX how does the useMemo benefit me here?

Comment: @taat With it you don't need a separate state atom for `polylines` that could get out of sync with `activities`.

Comment: @AKX will this have any effect if say I was to use redux in the future to store the activities state?

Comment: No. Any read-only data that you directly derive from other data (be that from React state, Redux state, the Internet (as in here with SWR), etc.) shouldn't be `state`, but derived via a pure function and then possibly memoized with `useMemo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

1. Move the logic that depends on the api data to a separate useEffect Hook. So that the logic for setting the polyline array will be calculated only when the api data is loaded.

```
useEffect(() => { 
if(activites.length){
    setPolylineArray();
}
    setIsLoading(false);
}, [activites])
```

2. Make the useEffect hook async and await the api call using a immediately invoked function. Await the api response and pass the activity data as a parameter since the setActivities function will not have time to complete.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  (async () => {
    const activities= await getActivityData();
    setPolylineArray(activities);
    setIsLoading(false);
  })();
}, [])
```

Comment: An effect hook can't be made async, because async functions always implicitly return a promise, and the only two valid return values for an effect hook are `undefined` or a (cleanup) function.

Comment: @AKX I have updated the code with immediately invoked functions so the cleanup function will be triggered.

Comment: That also won't work because `setPolylineArray` expects to be able to read the `activites` state atom, which isn't set here.

Comment: @AKX yes true. Thanks for pointing that out. So, an option would be to pass the activity data as a function parameter to 'setPolylineArrary' function since the' setActivities' function will not have time to complete?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this potentially.

This way you can hopefully guarantee the data is available before trying to access it.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setActivitieData().then(() => {
    setPolylineArray();
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
}, []);
```

Another route would be to pass the data down as well like the following:

**Note**: I fixed some spelling so this may not copy/paste for you.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setActivitiesData().then((activities) => {
    setPolylineArray(activities);
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
}, []);

const getActivityData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/data");

  return response.data;
};

const setActivitiesData = async () => {
  const activityData = await getActivityData();
  setActivities(activityData);
  return activityData
};

const setPolylineArray = (activities) => {
  // Do what you want with activities here
};
```